# ASP.NET Routing causes pages resources not to load

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, url-routing

I have a *Web Forms Application* under ASP.NET 4.0 *C#*. Well I started thinking about applying pages routing in order to mask my internal resource organization, so I asked in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636087/how-to-specify-url-mappings-in-asp-net-4-0-when-parameters-are-involved) and accepted the answer.

### A little background

My problem is that, when applying a route, the considered page will be routed correctly, meaning that I reach the page through a different path (logical and not physical), but images, styles and external resources are not rendered correctly (not at all).

But let's be more detailed. I added some basic routes for my pages as follows in the `Global.asax` file as follows:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Registering routes
    this.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
  }

  void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
  }

  void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
  }
  void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ... 
  }

  void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
  }

  void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes) {
    // Handling blog posts
    routes.MapPageRoute(
      "BlogRoot",
      "blog/posts",
      "~/Blog.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute(
      "BlogPosts",
      "blog/posts/{post-id}",
      "~/BlogPost.aspx");
  }

</script>
```

## The problem

Well, at a certain point, when I want to try my new paths, I do the following. Normally, to view my blog I always did: `http://localhost/MyWebSite/Blog.aspx` and my blog posts all showed. I did that again and no problem. Then I try typing: `http://localhost/MyWebSite/blog/posts` and the page is correctly routed. But there is a problem. The browser does not load images and styles.

#### I suspect...

It is like it tries to get images and style links starting from the url that I provided, but being that a logical one, it will fail! The page looks with the content, and the content is all there, but when it comes to images, css stuff and everything that is linked from somewhere outside the page itself, well it is not loaded by the browser.

I wanted to inspect my html, but it is not strange, it is simply as it normally is even when I did not apply routing. So the following is an excerpt of my page showing some image links and some css inclusions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>
  This is my blog
</title>
<meta name="author" content="Me, myself and I" />
<meta name="keywords" content="blog, personal information, personal page" />
<meta name="description" content="Personal Blog" />
<meta name="language" content="en-us" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Me - Year" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/FavIco.jpg" />
<link href="Styles/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/Style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...

My web site is structured in this way, in the root folder I have all my web pages and there is also a folder called `Images` where, inside, there are all images. In the root folder I also have the folder `Styles` with all css stylesheet inside it. There is also a folder called `Scripts`.
```

The following is another excerpt, showing a part of my `body`:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="navbar">
      <span id="WebSite_SiteMapPath"><a href="#WebSite_SiteMapPath_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" height="0" width="0" src="/WebResource.axd?d=YSaZQjo4n2xp9k-WqUJlK9ILtJOv6g5YNS2VyAf4VpYsZPmq-FcXDtnA5jQ1uPO3rQgDza-fEJKO1qU_C8uSY-WJiCQ7055T8wpvl9SIRFc1&amp;t=634608253861201595" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
         <span>
            <span class="sitenav">Home page</span>
         </span><a id="WebSite_SiteMapPath_SkipLink"></a>
       </span>
    </div>
   ...
```

I think that somehow the browser is trying to use the address provided in order to attach it to the `src` stuff it finds and determine the exact location of resources. But being this a logical address it fails. I think many people use routing, how do they solve this? Talking about best practice as well?

Thankyou

Comment: Can you show how an image-tag is rendered in the resulting html?

Comment: Done! It should suffice I think, there are css inclusions and also images inclusions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's because your css/script includes are relative links to the current page, and because your routed URL has an additional level in the URL, they browser is requesting the wrong URL. Best thing to do is let ASP.NET Resolve this for you, so instead of doing:

```
<link href="Scripts/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Try this:

```
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I can apply some edits later when I am off work, but should I do this for all my links??? Please also note that i have dynamic content inserted by users that writes links to images and stuff... Isn't it a little bit inconvenient?

Comment: I think this would be the most reliable, although there are other alternatives (e.g. make all your includes runat=server and start the URL with ~/). If you could guarantee that your site runs off the root (you seem to be using an application called MyWebSite, so you're not on the root), you could make your links root relative and start with /). If you are using relative URLs you have to be aware of the URL structure, you don't want to stop css/scripts from loading because you changed a route.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense, you're right. Using paths starting from root might be good I think. Can I have routes also for them. Consider I have a link to an image or script, like the one you reported in your answer, can I insert a rule to map styles like `style/{style-name}` and have redirect to that directory and use that path in my links? I mean the logical path for my links as well?

Comment: With relative links, the browser is going to try make a request to /MyWebSite/blog/posts/style/{filename}, so you would have to set up a route to blog/posts/style/{filename}. This doesn't seem like a nice idea, because you would have to do this for different pages, and if you change your URL structure, if you forget to update these routes, your css/scripts will break. It will be a lot easier to base your css/scripts against the root. Hope this helps!