# How to use ASP.net Routing to make url friendly

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, ektron

I have the following pages:

```
Default.aspx
find_provider.aspx --> (has a search which takes the user to each provider page) --> provider.aspx?id={####}
news.aspx --> (has links to each news) --> article.aspx?id={####}
health.aspx --> (has links to each event) --> event.aspx?id={####}
patinfo.aspx --> (has links to each info) --> info.aspx?id={####}
```

Although the page are easy to remember but not the ID.

For example, in the `find_provider.aspx` when a search is performed, there are three results which takes to `provider.aspx` page, each with a unique ID (with more added in the future):

```
Bolt, John MD --> provider.aspx?id=90
Barry, Brent MD --> provider.aspx?id=1090
Carson, John MD --> provider.aspx?id=10
```

How can I set up my web site where I an define what each page's ID will be for making it user and search friendly?

For example:

```
Bolt, John MD --> provider.aspx/johnbolt
Barry, Brent MD --> provider.aspx/brentbarry
Carson, John MD --> provider.aspx/johncarson
```

Also, the same for the `article.aspx`, `event.aspx`, and `info.aspx` and so on...

I am using Ektron CMS and not a MVC in the backend, if it helps to know.

I looked into ASP.net Routing but wasn't sure how to implement it as I am totally new to this process.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Ektron, have you tried using the aliasing feature?  This allows for friendly URLs to be created within the CMS.  There are different types of aliasing avaiable, please see [here](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v9.10/Reference/Web/EktronReferenceWeb.html#URL_Aliasing/URL_Aliasing.htm) for more information.

It is possible to create friendly aliases to a user's profile by creating an Automatic Aliasing rule for Users.

Alternatively, you may be using Smartforms to store information about your Providers. If so, you can create Automatic Aliases for Content by mapping a rule to either your folder structure or a taxonomy.

You can find all these settings in your Workarea here: Settings > Configuration > URL Aliasing.  By default aliases are turned off so you will need to enable the alias types you require in the Settings page within the URL Aliasing section.

Comment: The only issue is if the Content Title has a comma: `Matt, Burns MD`, it will be `Matt,_Burns_MD.aspx`. Which works except I want to remove the comma and make it `Matt_Burns_MD.aspx` or `MattBurnsMD.aspx`. How would I do that? I updated my question to show you. I couldn't find the `,` to replace with `nothing`.

Comment: I believe you can set up character replacements for each character that you want to replace.  Its at the bottom of the page where you configure the aliases. You should be able to replace comma with empty string.

Comment: My bad I thought it accepted an empty string. The only other suggestion I can make is to enforce removal of the comma from the content title. This can be achieved using a CMS Extension triggered by the OnAfterPublish event. If you still need the title with the comma, you could create an additional field in your Smartform to hold it in that format.

Comment: Otherwise, aliases could be manually created so you could set any value you like - but that may not be a good idea depending on how many items we are talking about.

Comment: The content title might have to be changed or I wonder if there is another method I can use. But you are right, automatic aliasing is what I will need :)

Comment: Thank you. SO didn't allow me to until now :)